# Netbeans start page unresponsive

Tags: netbeans, visual-glitch

I downloaded a plugin for a theme from a tutorial video and after re-opening the app my IDE does not respond to any buttons and the interface is also messed up. I tried re-installing netbeans and rebooting my computer but that did not help.

[image: netbeans start page]

Clicking plugins on the top of my screen just opens a blank page so I cant even remove the downloaded plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by navigating to Library/Application Support/Netbeans/16/modules
and deleting the plugin I had downloaded manually